# Jetty Server exceptions while using in jersey framework

Tags: maven, jetty, java-8, jersey-2.0

I am trying to use Jetty HTTPserver with jersey framework to make RESTful services. The code used is pretty simple:

```java
URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(9998).build();
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig().packages("main.java");
        Server server = JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(baseUri, config);
```

I am using maven to build the project with Java8 and following versions for jersey-container and jetty:
jersey-container-jetty-http - 2.17
jetty-server - 9.2.0.v20140526

But running the server is giving me AbstractMethodError. Here's the full stack trace:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.jetty.JettyHttpContainerProvider.createContainer(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Application;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.jetty.JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(JettyHttpContainerFactory.java:116)
        at main.java.Main.startServer(Main.java:43)
        at main.java.Main.main(Main.java:76)
        ... 6 more
```

Have you guys encountered this before and would anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: Please paste stack trace with exception.

Comment: Possibly a versioning conflict. Can you post all your dependencies.